# recyler listview with textureview is slow while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, media-player, surfaceview

I have **recyler listview** with **TextureView** and i am setting the URI(which is video from raw folder) to texture view and Adapter implements  **TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener** inteface after this i am getting following methods

1. onSurfaceTextureAvailable
2. onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged
3. onSurfaceTextureDestroyed

In **onSurfaceTextureAvailable** i am setting my MediaPlayer and start video. But the issue is while scrolling the list it gets stucked.(and slow loading).

Following is my code.

Thanks in advance.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener  {

private List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =null;
Uri uri;


public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Model> l) {
    this.list = l;
    this.context = context;
    uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.malhari1);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());

    holder.textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    System.out.println("onSurfaceTextureAvailable");

    setMediaPlayer(surface, uri);
}

private void setMediaPlayer(SurfaceTexture surface, Uri uri) {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surface));
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
       // mediaPlayerTemp = mediaPlayer;
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
  System.out.println("onSurfaceTextureDestroyed");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
}


public  class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView name;
    TextureView textureView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        textureView = (TextureView) 
 itemView.findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    }
}

  }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MyAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,list);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    setList();

}

private void setList() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setName("Name : "+i);
        list.add(model);
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to play video in Recycler view on scroll, please have a look on below libraries:
1) [Toro](https://github.com/eneim/Toro)

2) [VideoPlayerManager](https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager)

3) [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Comment: ExoPlayer is an alternative to Android’s MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Achieve that by first downloading the videos from url and then playing it with custom player. Here is how i did :

1) Get all url's need to be played

2) Start downloading videos (in queue) from urls in local storage and keep a flag in preferences (that a video is already downloaded or not)

3) Assign urls to Adapter in which initialize object of video player controller that handles video playbacks

4) Set addOnScrollListener to check which position/video is currently visible and check if video is already downloaded or not if yes then play it.